# Unable to deploy Contact Salutation values translations in SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, translation, translation-workbench, customobjecttranslation

I want to be able to deploy Contact Salutation values translations in an environment, from my SFDX project.

My Contact's object translations representation is this:

[image]

The content of the file `Salutation.fieldTranslation-meta.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomFieldTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label><!-- Salutation --></label>
    <name>Salutation</name>
    <picklistValues>
        <masterLabel>Dr.</masterLabel>
        <translation><!-- Dr. --></translation>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <masterLabel>Mr.</masterLabel>
        <translation>Herr</translation>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <masterLabel>Mrs.</masterLabel>
        <translation>Frau</translation>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <masterLabel>Prof.</masterLabel>
        <translation><!-- Prof. --></translation>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <masterLabel>Prof. Dr.</masterLabel>
        <translation><!-- Prof. Dr. --></translation>
    </picklistValues>
</CustomFieldTranslation>
```

If I try to deploy the `objectTranslations` folder in my sandbox:

[image]

Or via command:

`sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath /Users/endrit.sino/Documents/Repos/salesforce/force-app/main/default/objectTranslations --json`

I get the error: `Cannot translate standard field: Contact.Salutation (3:13)`

Full json error report:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "columnNumber": "13",
      "lineNumber": "3",
      "error": "Cannot translate standard field: Contact.Salutation (3:13)",
      "fullName": "Contact-de",
      "type": "CustomObjectTranslation",
      "filePath": "force-app/main/default/objectTranslations/Contact-de/Contact-de.objectTranslation-meta.xml",
      "problemType": "Error"
    }
  ],
  "name": "DeployFailed",
  "message": "Deploy failed.",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "actions": [],
  "commandName": "SourceDeployCommand",
  "data": [
    {
      "columnNumber": "13",
      "lineNumber": "3",
      "error": "Cannot translate standard field: Contact.Salutation (3:13)",
      "fullName": "Contact-de",
      "type": "CustomObjectTranslation",
      "filePath": "force-app/main/default/objectTranslations/Contact-de/Contact-de.objectTranslation-meta.xml",
      "problemType": "Error"
    }
  ],
  "stack": ...
```

Any idea how the `Salutation` values translations could be deployed?

It would be awful for our DevOps processes, if would have to circumvent this by a manual process in place. :(